# API Controller - Add Custom Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

Would it be possible that I can add custom properties or attributes to my ApiControllers (or Routes) so that I can receive and make decisions based on them within a DelegatingHandler?

Maybe there is some way to inject into the RouteData where I could retreive my value from :

```
request.GetRouteData()
```

I see a MS_SubRoutes in here but not sure how to modify it or how to go about this.  Appreciate the help.  Psuedo handler code below of what i'd like to do.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // check the value of the custom property.
            if (!request.Properties["MyCustomProp"].ToString().Contains("XXXX"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, HttpResponses.WorkflowServiceDisabledException));
            }
            //  otherwise do this
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can do this creation a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`: https://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

Comment: Not sure if I am misunderstanding but handlers will see requests before controllers